# php linebreak in a math calculation (not strings)

Tags: php, html

How do you do a line break in php for a line that performs a calculation? For example, how can I add a line break in the following code? A br doesn't seem to work...

```
echo 10+20; //now I want a new line after this calculation
```

Comment: In what way does it "not seem to work"?

Comment: `echo (10+20).'<br>'`

Comment: `echo 10+20 . "<br>";

echo "broken";` worked fine for me. `30
broken` in 2 lines. If you're wanting to write to a file then that's a different thing. Use `"\n"`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Of course it's worth noting that the space before the `.` is significant on your code - `10+20."<br>"` will not work because it sees it as a decimal point.

Comment: `10+20.."<br>"` works though.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol ah yes, good point. I tried it with no space and got back a syntax error.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol OP might have been doing `echo 10+20. "<br>";` so we don't know exactly *what* they're *really* using/tried.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol where can I find the double dot manual in php.net ?? thanks :D

Comment: @Andrew You can't, but it's a consequence of the parser - `20.` is read as a floating-point number, then the next `.` can only be the concatenation operator. It works in JavaScript too - `20..toString()` is `"20"`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol nice trick :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try either of those:

```
echo (10+20) . PHP_EOL; // This is if your headers are set as plain text. 
echo (10 + 20). '<br/>'; // if html headers
```

Comment: Or `10+20 . '<br/>'`, or `10+20..'<br/>'`, or `$ten = 10; $twenty = 20; echo $ten+$twenty.'<br/>';`, or infinitely many other options.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol +1 on your comment ;-) I learned something about the double dot today ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can add calculation and after new line by adding new `echo "<br>"`:

```
echo 10+20; //now I want a new line after this calculation
echo "<br>";
echo 23+22;
```